# Is it okay to shut off the cold water(blue tubing) to the water heater with the main water still on?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater, bathtub

We have a leak in the bathtub faucet that needs to be addressed, but getting to the main water shutoff is located in a crawl space beneath the adjacent unit.

Is it okay if I shut off the cold water supply to the hot water heater for a few hours, while I repair the tub faucet?

When I turned it off just briefly, it started making an almost pressurizing noise, which had me a little worried. Might have just been the water retreating down the piping, but I wanted to make sure

Comment: Turning off the cold water supply to the water heater won't do anything to the cold water supply at the tub faucet...

Comment: @mmathis Yes, but the faucet leak is severe enough that the water heater's H20 supply will deplete pretty quickly if I can cut off it's intake. Once it's drained, I'm assuming I can begin work. I've gathered that I should shut off the water heater itself initially

Comment: @Jimbo1128 -- what about the cold supply to the bathtub faucet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but...

- Turn off the water heater first. You don't want the elements heating without a full tank. Be sure to fill it completely before turning it back on.
- Expect some residual pressure for a bit. Open a few taps low in the house to help.

Comment: And by "fill completely" that means open hot water faucets and wait until air stops coming out with the water. Only THEN should you turn the water heater on.